# Nginx - try_files: How to set up a remote file (url)?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, nginx-config

I have a React single page application that uses browser history and Basename is "invite", which is my current nginx configuration using native html files:

```
server{
    listen 9999;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/activity_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/activity_error.log;
    location /invite {
        root html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /invite/index.html;
    }
}
```

The above configuration works very well.

But I want to set my local html file to an html file on cdn. What should I do? This is my pseudo code:

```
server{
    listen 9999;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/activity_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/activity_error.log;
    location /invite {
        root html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri https://mycdn.com/invite/index.html;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter in the `try_files` statement can specify a URI for an *internal redirect* only. Use a named location instead.

For example:

```
location /invite {
    ...
    try_files $uri @redirect;
}
location @redirect {
    return 301 https://mycdn.com/invite/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

---

To use a reverse proxy instead of a redirect, use:

```
location @redirect {
    rewrite ^ /invite/index.html break;
    proxy_pass https://mycdn.com;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect, can I use other methods to proxy html files on cdn?